# Unable to open a quick create form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm, dynamics-crm-365

In our Dynamics 365 instance, we're trying to open a quick create form for an entity called `SourceAssessment` using the [code example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj602956.aspx#BKMK_openQuickCreate)

```
var thisEntity = {
    entityType: "SourceAssessment",
    id: Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()
};
var callback = function (obj) {
    console.log("Created new " + obj.savedEntityReference.entityType + " named '" + 

obj.savedEntityReference.name + "' with id:" + obj.savedEntityReference.id);
}
var setName = { name: "Child account of " + Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue() 

};
Xrm.Utility.openQuickCreate("SourceAssessment", thisEntity, setName).then(callback, function 

(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

- The line `Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()` throws

  > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entity' of null(…)
- The line `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue()` throws

  > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of null(…)
- The line
  `Xrm.Utility.openQuickCreate("SourceAssessment", thisEntity, setName).then(callback, function (error) {`
  `console.log(error.message);`
  `});` throws

> The entityLogicalName isn't valid. This value can't be null or empty, and it must represent an entity in the organization.

Comment: Where are you executing this code? Inside CRM?

Comment: @Sxntk In Console

Comment: Rewrite your code and make it calls after Xrm.Entity.data.entity is not undefined so you can see if you are not calling it too soon.

Comment: @Sxntk `Xrm.Entity.data.entity` in all cases is `undefined`. What shall we do?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I know you are opening a quick create form but you are using the developer console, are you testing the code or where is the final place this will execute

Comment: @Sxntk This should work in Dynamics CRM only but I was testing it for my understanding. Anyways, I'll try to execute on `Form_Load`

Answer (score 2):

When using the developer console to execute code, you have to first switch to the correct frame, in order to access the `Xrm.Page` object of the form.

In Chrome you can switch frames here:

[image]

The frame you want to be in is usually called **customScriptsFrame**, and other times it is one of the numbered contentIFrames.

Comment: Okey, I tried this trick as well. In none of the frames this is working.